# BCP import from multiple text files to multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I could successfully export data on multiple files from different database tables of MS SQL using BCP. But now I have to import those files to the corresponding tables in another database with same schema and structure.The databases are in different network.As there are large number of tables, importing manually every table with corresponding file is not possible.
How to achieve this?

Comment: I assume that your destination database server has access to network location where all exported data files are stored, if yes than you can do `Bulk Insert` as below `BULK INSERT DestTable FROM '\\NetworkPath_exportedfile_data.dat' WITH (FORMATFILE = '\\NetworkPath_exportedfile_format.Fmt');`

Comment: Can you just write a script that does that for all tables one by one? Most likely it's even possible with .bat files

Comment: I used the following script to create commands and I execute those commands from a batch file.

SELECT 'bcp '           --bcp
+  QUOTENAME(DB_NAME())+ '.'               --database name
+  QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID))+ '.'  -- schema
+  QUOTENAME(name)                         -- table
+ ' out c:\temp\'                          -- output directory
+  REPLACE(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id),' ','') + '.' 
+  REPLACE(name,' ','')                    -- file name
+ '.txt -T -c /t,'   -- extension, security 
FROM sys.tables

Comment: Jigar, Do you mean I have to write script for each table? Also, does it support for other file type like txt, csv etc

Comment: Yes, you need to write script for each table, or you can loop thru. 
For CSV file you can use following, `BULK INSERT DestTable FROM '\\NetworkPath_exportedfile_data.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ';', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')`

Answer (score 0):

As you have got the files, you can have a single batch script with BCP commands to load to destination tables:

**Batch file: SampleBatch.bat**

```
bcp.exe DBName.SchemaName.TableName1 IN "YourPathContainingDataFile1" -c -T -S "TargetServerName"   
bcp.exe DBName.SchemaName.TableName2 IN "YourPathContainingDataFile2" -c -T -S "TargetServerName"
```

Now, call the batch file in the command prompt

```
c:\users\venkat>SampleBatch.bat
```